# Mysql Check If Data Exists, otherwise Query to Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to avoid 2 queries here.. so what i'm trying to do is First, check if data exists on that table.. if it does exists, then fetch data from that table.. otherwise, query to another table.. my script looks like this

```
select if( exists(
    select 1
    from emoney_promo.promo_participants pp
    left join emoney_promo.promo_dtl_child pdc on pdc.active_promo_id = pp.id
    where pp.applied_to = '4518'
),
(
    select pdc.*
    from emoney_promo.promo_participants pp
    left join emoney_promo.promo_dtl_child pdc on pdc.active_promo_id = pp.id
    where pp.applied_to = '4518'
),
(
    select pp.id as pp_id, pv.id as pv_id, pv.validation_type as pv_validationtype, pv.validation_value as pv_validationvalue,
    pc.id as pc_id, pc.tanggal as pc_tanggal, pc.counter as pc_counter, pc.member_id as pc_memberid, pc.mid as pc_mid,
    pd.min_amount_trx as pd_minamounttrx, pd.max_amount_trx as pd_maxamounttrx, pd.cashback_type as pd_cashbacktype
    from emoney_promo.promo_validation pv
    join emoney_promo.promo_counter pc on pv.promo_id = pc.promo_id
    join emoney_promo.promo_dtl pd on pd.promo_id = pv.promo_id
    join emoney_promo.promo_participants pp on pp.promo_id = pv.promo_id
    where pc.member_id = '0867667762'
    and pp.applied_to = '4518'
    and pc.mid = '4518'
));
```

But it shows `Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`
is there any way to achieve this? Once again, i'm trying to avoid 2 queries, that's why i'm using this :)

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid two queries?

Comment: It's `IF(boolean_expression, then_value, else_value)`, but you are not selecting one value each for `then_value` and `else_value`, but several. This cannot work. This is what the error message says.

Comment: Your exists query makes little sense by the way. What do you think the outer join does? Either there is a pp record with applied_to = '4518' or not. Outer joining another table doesn't change this.

Comment: And if you don't find a pp record with applied_to = '4518' in the first query, you wont't find it in the second either.

Comment: @TZHX humm performance maybe? so the program won't have to query to database 2 times :D

Comment: @thekucay have you noticed that as a performance problem? it shouldn't be, if you write your application correctly, and would make it so that you make *either* one or two queries to the DB rather than the guaranteed two you currently make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned: when your first query doesn't return any record, the second won't either (as you are applying the same criteria). So you can simply execute the first query only and either you get a result or not.

Anyway, the typical method to write such query as you describe is:

```
select a, b, c from ... -- <== first query
union all
select d, e, f from ... -- <== second query
where not exists (<first query again>)
```

As to performence: yes you send just one query to the DBMS and save time thus. However, the combined query is more complicated than the separate ones. This can take way longer to execute. I'd usually go for two separate queries hence, but sometimes it may make sense to have such a combined query (especially when the first query almost always returns no rows).

Comment: Well, if so, i will try to use 2 queries then. Thanks for your suggestion :D